# Adding margins makes last column make new row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

"So I have the below code, I want to add margins to separate the columns and not having them touch each other. However, every time I do, the last column goes below and creates a new row. I'm using Bootstrap. How do I prevent this from happening?"

```
<div class="container attributes-div">
        <div class="row attributes">
            <div class="col-xl-4 attribute-center info-1">
                <img class="attribute-pic" src="house2.png">
                <h3>Quality Cleaning</h3>
                <h5>We strive to leave your home spotless! It is always our 
                goal to have your clean at it's best!</h5>
            </div>

        <div class="col-xl-4 attribute-center info-2 middle-attribute-margin">
            <img class="attribute-pic" src="dollarsign2.png">
            <h3>Affordable Rates</h3>
            <h5>We offer REASONABLE RATES that won't hurt your pocket!</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-4 attribute-center info-1 info-3">
            <img class="attribute-pic" src="maid.png">
            <h3>Professional Staff</h3>
            <h5>We listen to our customers and make sure to leave each of 
            their homes to their liking. If you aren't satisfied, we aren't 
            satisfied either!</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"Below is my CSS:"

```
.attributes-div{
margin-top: 200px;
max-width: 90%;
    }


.attribute-pic{
width: 50px;
   }

.attribute-center{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
  }

.info-1{
background: linear-gradient(70deg,#F0E4F0,#eef2f3,#F0E4F0);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .info-2{
background: linear-gradient(70deg,#dfeff5,#eef2f3,#dfeff5);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: you are using bootstrap so you need to follow bootstrap rules ... it's logical that you get new row since you are already using 12 columns, reduce and use less and rely on offset ... or use only `col` to be able to add margin

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you said. Answer was so simple! Thanks! I've just had about 3 months learning to code so I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Well in bootstrap the max is 12, and each of those boxes are value 4... 4*3 = 12 + your margins make it more than 12 going to the next line. I'd suggest maybe making the boxes a value of 3 (value meaning like `col-xl-3`)

Answer (score 0):

You must not use `margin` for the columns. Instead use a `w-100` div inside the columns and use `margin` or `padding` for it.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container attributes-div">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 ">
      <div class="w-100 px-3 bg-primary">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="house2.png">
        <h3>Quality Cleaning</h3>
        <h5>We strive to leave your home spotless! It is always our 
          goal to have your clean at it's best!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 ">
      <div class="w-100 px-3 bg-primary ">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="dollarsign2.png">
        <h3>Affordable Rates</h3>
        <h5>We offer REASONABLE RATES that won't hurt your pocket!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="w-100 px-3 bg-primary ">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="maid.png">
        <h3>Professional Staff</h3>
        <h5>We listen to our customers and make sure to leave each of 
          their homes to their liking. If you aren't satisfied, we aren't 
          satisfied either!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want equal height columns, use `d-flex` and `flex-columns` for the columns and `h-100` for the `w-100` divs.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container attributes-div">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-3 bg-primary">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="house2.png">
        <h3>Quality Cleaning</h3>
        <h5>We strive to leave your home spotless! It is always our goal to have your clean at it's best!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-3 bg-primary ">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="dollarsign2.png">
        <h3>Affordable Rates</h3>
        <h5>We offer REASONABLE RATES that won't hurt your pocket!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-3 bg-primary ">
        <img class="attribute-pic" src="maid.png">
        <h3>Professional Staff</h3>
        <h5>We listen to our customers and make sure to leave each of their homes to their liking. If you aren't satisfied, we aren't satisfied either!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pabpyb